# Tentativa de acessar browserconfig.xml pode ser algum tipo de ataque?

Tags: xss, csrf, ddos, exploit

Aqui na empresa onde trabalho, colocamos em um determinado sistema, feito em Laravel 4, um sistema de envio de e-mails toda vez que ocorre algum tipo de erro em requisições.

Começamos a desconfiar de algumas atividades, que listarei abaixo, pois algumas vêem de IPS que não são aqui do Brasil, além de ter algumas urls em requisições que realmente não fazem nenhum sentido.

Eis alguns deles (substituí nossa url pela palavra `url`):

```
url/browserconfig.xml //Esse foi campeão de erros, com 19
url/js/===n
url/js/],_default:x.support.htmlSerialize 
url/js/,data:n}).done(function(e){o=arguments,s.html(i?x(=
url/js/).enctype,t.html5Clone=
url/js/!=typeof
```

Todas essas requisições estão retornando erro 404.

O mais intrigante é essa aparente tentativa de exploit em javascript, ou algo do tipo, pois o IP vem da Itália - `93.34.104.108`.

Alguém sabe de que se trata isso?

São apenas erros que podem ser gerados em alguns navegadores, ou são tentativas de encontrar vulnerabilidades?